# What is the origin of giving certain corners within houses own name?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, culture

Thanks to another question on this forum i learned that the south-western corner of a house has its own name: 奥. I was very surprised of this notion and could not make any sense why there might be necessity for giving corners unique names.

- Could you provide an ethymology to make the purpose of naming comprehensible?
- What are further names for particular places in a house?

Comment: [《爾雅·釋宮》](http://ctext.org/er-ya/shi-gong/zh)：「西南隅謂之奧。西北隅謂之屋漏。東北隅謂之宦。東南隅謂之㝔。」 Thus, the southwestern corner is 奧, northwestern is 屋漏, northeastern is 宦, and southeastern is 㝔.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of names for other corners of the house, but the southwestern corner is considered traditionally as the privileged site suitable for worshipping deities.

> 《禮·曲禮》 爲人子者，居不主奧。

"The child does not live in the southwestern corner." In other words, one should show deference to one's parents by yielding the southwestern corner.